# What to set Data in Ajax if I don't send any data to WebMethod in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I wants to retrieve data from server side using Ajax and WebMethod

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    url: "GPCreateCheque.aspx/getOpenRequestNo",
    data:"{}",

    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {                            
        alert(data.d);                            
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
})
```

My WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<string> getOpenRequestNo()
    {
        string[] result = { };
        List<string> records = new List<string>();

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [RequestID] FROM [Customer] WHERE Approved is null ORDER BY [ID] DESC";

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                records.Add(rd["RequestID"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return records;
    }
```

It throws error

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. If I am calling another webmethod from the same ajax, that is working fine,

In that WebMethod I am passing parameter, So I should specify like below.

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    "vendorID": $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlVendorID :selected').text()
}),
```

But here I don't want to send any data to server, So How should I specify the data field

**UPDATE**

> I found the problem, I can return string, But I cannot return the List on ajax.

**How to return the string on AJAX?**

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for my question, Finally I found in Jquery.com

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",                 
    url: "GPCreateCheque.aspx/getOpenRequestNo",                     
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {                            
        alert(data.d);                            
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
})
```